# Android: How to create a versatile area to swap out different views in XML layout file

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-imagebutton

I want to be able to switch out text views, image buttons, and map views all in one area in a single activity. What would I place in the xml file so that I can fill in whatever type of view is necessary at the given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a `FrameLayout` which can serve as a container for different `Fragment`s.

Useful link: [Building a dynamic UI with Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

As a first step, you can create different `Fragment`s for really different topics (example: one login screen and one map) If you need only to change a small thing consider working with `ViewStub` (lets you lazily expand a `View`) or change the visibility of `View`s according to your requirement.

Comment: One quick question: would I need to swap out fragments for image views, text, etc? Or would it all fit into one fragment?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds pretty much like the description of fragments.